# Delta - epsilon problem from Spivak's Calculus.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The excerpt is taken from the *Answers to Selected Problems* section.

[textbook solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnlEc.png)

How is

$$  \mathsf{min}\left(1,\frac{\mathsf{min}\left(1,\epsilon/(2(|a|^2+1)\right)}{2(|a|+1)}\right)                $$

equal to

$$ \mathsf{min}\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|^2+1)(|a|+1)}\right)   $$

?

The assumption is that $a$ is any real number and $\epsilon>0$, but if $a=0$ and $\epsilon=8$

$$   \mathsf{min}\left(1,\frac{\mathsf{min}\left(1,\epsilon/(2(|a|^2+1)\right)}{2(|a|+1)}\right) = 1/2   $$

and

$$  \mathsf{min}\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|^2+1)(|a|+1)}\right) = 1    $$

If the condition $0<\epsilon<1$ is imposed upon $\epsilon$, then the equality holds, but the expression $$ \mathsf{min}\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|^2+1)(|a|+1)}\right)   $$ becomes completely superfluous, since

$$ \mathsf{min}\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|^2+1)(|a|+1)}\right) =  \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|^2+1)(|a|+1)}  $$

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are right that for some choices of $\epsilon$ and $a$ you don't get an equality. On the other hand, in the "grand scheme of things" it all doesn't matter. What the author has shown is that, for a chosen $\epsilon\gt 0$ you can choose $\delta\gt 0$ somehow so that some inequality holds. The formula for $\delta$ may have an error, but the point is not really to calculate $\delta$ - the point is just to show that such a $\delta$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right. The equality

> $$  \mathsf{min}\left(1,\frac{\mathsf{min}\left(1,\epsilon/(2(|a|^2+1)\right)}{2(|a|+1)}\right)      = \mathsf{min}\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|^2+1)(|a|+1)}\right) $$

assumes

$$  \mathsf{min}\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|a|^2+1)}\right) = \frac{\epsilon}{2(|a|^2+1)} $$

which is only correct if

$$\frac{\epsilon}{2(a^2+1)} \le 1 \iff \epsilon \le 2a^2+2$$

This is always true, for all values of $a$, **if** $\epsilon \le 2$; but not for all $\epsilon$ indeed.